# How do I eliminate some of the queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

ok so i am doing this

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <span><%= course.not_competent %></span> <span><%= course.novice %></span></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

this in my Course Model I have this

```
def novice
  self.courses_users.low_scores.collect{|score| score.user.username}.join(', ')
end

def not_competent
  self.courses_users.really_low_scores.collect{|score| score.user.username}.join(', ')
end
```

the problem is this approach will run thousands of queries....is there a better way that will not bring down the DB

Comment: Use `:include` on the finder I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

right @Zabba , try at first to change the call that populate @courses and add something similar to this params

```
:include => [{:courses_users => :low_scores}]
```

or chain

```
.includes([{:courses_users => :low_scores}])
```

(i suppose low_scores is another associations of your model )

in this manner Activerecord change the first query you have with inclusion of the nested tables.in this [ascii_cast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) some example .

hope it could be usefull